# Having trouble making a button that turns window.scrollBy() on/off

Tags: javascript, scroll, automation, setinterval, clearinterval

I'm trying to create a button that when clicked the window automatically scrolls, and when that same button is pressed again it turns off.

here is a fiddle of how far I've gotten so far:

https://jsfiddle.net/swurvinmervin/n7poL3hw/34/

HTML :

```html
<div class = "b">
<p>pretend button</p>
</div>
```

Style :

```css
div {
    width: 50px;
    height:5000px;
    background: red;
}
```

Javascript :

```js
var button = document.querySelector("div");

button.addEventListener("click",buttonFunction);

function buttonFunction() {
    if (button.classList.contains("b")){
        button.classList.add("a");
        button.classList.remove("b");
    } else {
        if (button.contains("a")){
            button.classList.add("b");
            button.classList.remove("a");
        }       
    }

    var i = 0;

    var winScroll = setInterval(function() {
        if (button.classList.contains("a")){
            window.scrollBy(0,500);
        } else {
            if(button.classList.contains("b") ){ 
                clearInterval(winScroll);
            }
        }  
    }, 200);
}
```

Comment: `if(button.contains("a")) {...}` lacks `classList`. `button.contains` is a method, but it requires a node as its argument, not a string. I suggest you to open the DevTools, there is useful information, like error messages ...

Comment: This is code I definitely should've slept on haha, thank you kind stranger!

Answer (score 1):

```
function buttonFunction() {
    if (button.classList.contains("b")){
        button.classList.add("a");
        button.classList.remove("b");
    } else {
        if (button.classList.contains("a")){
            button.classList.add("b");
            button.classList.remove("a");
        }       
    }

    var i = 0;

    var winScroll = setInterval(function() {
        if (button.classList.contains("a")){
            window.scrollBy(0,500);
        } else {
            if(button.classList.contains("b") ){ 
                clearInterval(winScroll);
            }
        }  `enter code here`
    }, 200);
}
```

there is an error in the if condition in else block it should be if (button.classList.contains("a") instead of if (button.contains("a")) classlist is missing before .contains